# Macro to define custom exception type - Bad Practice

Tags: c++, c++11, macros

Is using a c macro like the below to define an exception bad practice?

```
#define CUSTOM_EXCEPTION(name, msg) class name : std::exception { \
        virtual const char* what() const throw() { \
            return #msg; \
        } \
    };
```

I kind of like the idea of using a macro, because DRY, but I've heard bad things about using macros making code unmaintainable. Is there a better way to define a simple type macro returning a custom message?

Comment: Well for one, when do you say readability > writability? Do you need speed for what you are doing...? Less Profiling - Less Traceable - Harder to debug - Could Lead to severe Bugs

Comment: Macros are a powerful but primitive tool. It's easy to use them to make your code harder to read and more error-prone. I don't see that problem here.

Comment: `noexcept` > `throw()`